# NPM package error while import inside node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

When ever I setup this project, I am facing this error. This is happening for some of the packages, while importing them inside nodue_modules folder. This showing like :

```
 import type { Rect } from "./common";
 import type { Grid, ICellMapper } from "./common/grid";
```

Due to the string "type" after import, is causing this problem, I upgraded packages but doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: remove `type`, typescript is smart enough to import types when needed

Comment: Do you mean manually removing the type, from  node_modules. "import type" to "import"

Comment: `import { Rect } from "./common";`

Comment: This is inside node_moduls, not inside a ts file I am working, and lots of files inside node_modules showing this,

Comment: try updating typescript version

Comment: Increasing version showing error in most code.